# AngularJS ng-value boolean validation

Tags: validation, angularjs

To be specific: I have two radio buttons and their ng-model value must be boolean. Since this is not possible with normal html value property I found useful Angularjs ng-value. Problem is when I want to do some validation, when radio button ng-value="false" is selected it recognizes it as an empty ng-model and we have validation error.

**Example**: http://plnkr.co/edit/lvdNHZoSSN1nM6uLyc0Q?p=preview

Any clue how to tackle this?

Comment: Use a checkbox if you have only one truthy value.

Comment: I cannot use checkbox. Client wants to have 2 radio buttons and possibility that value can be null (both unselected)

Comment: If the client wants the radio button "look" but doesn't care about the type attribute on the input, then you could restyle a checkbox to look like a radio button using CSS.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug.

`value="true/false"` won't work because your radio inputs won't be initialized and checked correctly when your model is loaded, but `ng-value="true/false"` won't work because "false" selections will cause the form to be invalid.

I was having the same problem and reported it as an issue, but since there's no telling when it will be resolved, I also came up with a workaround: [ng-boolean-radio](https://github.com/michaelmoussa/ng-boolean-radio)

It basically converts your model's boolean true / false values into string "true" / "false" values, which match your form's string `value="true/false"` attributes. This will allow the corresponding radio inputs to be checked by default when the model loads. It will also allow you to save "false" values because `"false" != false`.

Finally, it preserves the boolean datatype by converting the string "true" / "false" values back to boolean true / false before saving them in the model.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5vDuTug0kvS3Ut58Lz9?p=preview

Problem is in the `required` attribute.

I believe using `ng-required="!user.gender"` is what you're looking for.

Edit: it seems that `ng-required`, while slightly better, still doesn't work fully.

My recommendation is to omit `require` completely and initialize your model with a default value:

`{gender: true}` (`false` will work too).

Comment: It is not working. It is working only if you select first true and then false. If you select false, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. Michael Moussa's directive was very good for debugging what the checkboxe's/radio button's actual `modelValue` is. As it turned out, a `modelValue` of `false` arrived `undefined` at the checkbox/radio button. Updating (from 1.2.0) to **angular 1.2.5** fixed the problem for me.