# Trouble implementing ng-boolean-radio - or how to use boolean values in select

Tags: angularjs

Regarding the answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048718/angularjs-ng-value-boolean-validation/16410891#16410891)

I'm trying to add this to my code and it's not working.

```
    <select ng-model="project.isBudgetFirm" ng-disabled="isSeller()" class="span8" ng-boolean-radio >
        <option value="true">firm</option>
        <option value="false">range....</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want radio buttons (since you're using ng-radio) don't use a select, use input type=radio:

```
<label>
    Firm
    <input type="radio"
           ng-model="project.isBudgetFirm"
           ng-disabled="isSeller()"
           value="true"
           ng-required="true"
           ng-boolean-radio />
</label>
<label>
    Range...
    <input type="radio" 
           ng-model="project.isBudgetFirm" 
           ng-disabled="isSeller()" 
           value="false" 
           ng-required="true" 
           ng-boolean-radio />
</label>
```

If you don't need to make it required or you have a default value, then replace value with ng-value and remove ng-required and ng-boolean-radio attributes.

Comment: Was hoping it would attach to any field type, but I guess it's specific to radio. I thought it was "simulating" radio types on other field types.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep a select then write a directive that requires the ngModelController and pushes a formatter and a parser in its $formatters and $parsers arrays.

The former will format the boolean model value to a string true or false. The latter will parse the string view value selected to a boolean value.